# I want to use VECM, does that mean all my variables should be stationary in the first difference at trend and intercept?

Tags: time-series, unit-root, vector-error-correction-model

All my variables are I(1) using none, and intercept models, but not stationary using trend and intercept models. Not sure if I can use these variables in VECM?

Comment: Your question implies that I(1) is stationary, but this is not the case. To run a VECM, you need variables that **(i)** are all I(1) individually and **(ii)** are cointegrated (there exists at least one linear combination which is I(0)).

Comment: ohh sorry, I didn't mention it, yes, my variables are cointegrated for sure. I am only concerned about the criteria of that I(1). I thought all the variables(first differenced) had to be stationary in all models (none, intercept, trand and intercept) then we can say they are stationary in I(1). But you are indicating that as long as they are stationary in one or more models, we can say they are I(1).

Comment: Not exactly. You have to find the appropriate model for unit root testing and conclude based on it, not on other models. I would also not use expressions such as *stationary in I(1)*.